# What type of methodology can I use to prove my concept in a journal other than real or simulative implementation?

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot

As I am willing to write a paper based on human-robot interaction where I am willing to suggest some ways to improve robot teleoperation in robotic competition scenarios. I have plans to go through some YouTube videos of some competitions and find out where the teleoperators are facing problems and ways to improve those. But the problem is, I can't implement those rather in real or in simulation (due to lack of resources). In that case, how should I be able to prove my suggestions so that they can be shown as a better way of operating robots?

Comment: you really need a proof of concept ... without it, how will you know that your idea actually works?